# Run time error - division by zero

Tags: c++

I have a run time issue when i debugged my script.

It says :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x002a4f8e in test2.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.
```

Although the line in question is a rand number generation.

```
if((rand() % miss) < 3){ //line 40
  int phit = (rand()% hit);
} else {
  bool pmiss = true;
}
```

Debugger stops at line 40 when it goes wrong (which i labelled above).

My full script is here:
http://www.paste.to/MzQ1ODM1

How should I have written the if statement if this causes such an error, i keep thinking like a PHP programmer which is v.frustrating to adapt!

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that `miss` is equal to zero.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i attatched a link to my full script. I gets a value during an if statement...but i globally set the variable =/
Value miss is 5 or should be at least.

Comment: miss is 0. Thus you are trying to divide a number by 0. Division by 0 is illegal and causes a cosmic disturbance! = Why you get an error, try to set miss to something other then 0.

Comment: int miss = 5; is set at line 29 so i thought it was set.

Comment: its set by an if. So it might be bugging, try setting it to 999999 at the start instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-declaring `miss` at line 30. That variable will be local to the *if* statement. *Therefore, the global `miss` will still have a value of zero.* Take out all those `int`, and also the `bool` inside the `if` statements!  Like this:

```
                            if(user_weapon == 'k'){
                                    miss = 5;
                                    hit = 5;
                            } else if(user_weapon == 'b'){
                                    miss = 2;
                                    hit = 3;
                            } else {
                                    invalid = true;
                            }
```

Comment: Ah yes, haven't noticed that. +1. Otherwise, it's still a good idea not to begin with 0 in the first place.

Comment: Also the `bool` in front of `invalid` has to go.

Comment: Ah so that explains it! Gosh it really is quite a scrict language =/ Guess it was bad to learn PHP first now =/

Answer (score 1):

line 29 and 32 should be

```
miss = 5

miss = 2
```

you are declaring a new local variable miss inside the if scope which means you are not changing the one declared at line 6

Comment: On the contrary, those local variables die with the if, but they dont change the var on line 6. so var on line 6 remains 0, and these two die. solution is the same

Answer (score 0):

The % (modulus) is the remnant of the division. So you divide a by b in a%b and get the remnant from it. If b is 0 (like in this case), you get an error.
Division by 0 is illegal and causes a cosmic disturbance (or code crash).
try setting the variable to another value.

Comment: I attatched my full script - the variable is set moments before which is why i don't understand the reason for it to have not set...

Comment: The if statement might be buggy, try setting it to 9999999 at the start and tell me if that fixes it (temporarily)